# requestPurchase RobotMedia doesn't do anything

Tags: android, in-app-billing

Hello everyone :) I'm trying to implement in-app billing in my application and watching the README of RobotMedia in GitHub i've done this:

i'm trying with this:

```
aba = new AbstractBillingActivity() {

        @Override
        public String getPublicKey() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public byte[] getObfuscationSalt() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSubscriptionChecked(boolean supported) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onRequestPurchaseResponse(String itemId, ResponseCode response) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onPurchaseStateChanged(String itemId, PurchaseState state) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onBillingChecked(boolean supported) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    };
```

Byt when i try to do:

```
aba.checkBillingSupported();
```

It gaves to me **NullPointerException** on the variable "aba"

***EDIT***

I have done this:

```
public class Index extends AbstractBillingActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_index);

        checkBillingSupported();


        Button buy = (Button) findViewById(R.id.compra);
        buy.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                requestPurchase("android.test.purchased");


            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public byte[] getObfuscationSalt() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPublicKey() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBillingChecked(boolean supported) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onSubscriptionChecked(boolean supported) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onPurchaseStateChanged(String itemId, PurchaseState state) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPurchaseResponse(String itemId, ResponseCode response) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Comment: don't you think that subclassing the abstract class should be through Your_class extends AbstractBillingActivity().

Answer (score -1):

If you're using `BillingController` directly you also need to implement [`IBillingObserver`](https://github.com/robotmedia/AndroidBillingLibrary/blob/master/AndroidBillingLibrary/src/net/robotmedia/billing/IBillingObserver.java), and `onPurchaseIntent` in particular.

You might want to start by looking at [DungeonsRedux](https://github.com/robotmedia/AndroidBillingLibrary/tree/master/DungeonsRedux) (the sample code) and maybe using [`AbstractBillingActivity`](https://github.com/robotmedia/AndroidBillingLibrary/blob/master/AndroidBillingLibrary/src/net/robotmedia/billing/helper/AbstractBillingActivity.java) first to get acquainted with IAB.

Regarding your latest edit, you shouldn't be creating activities with a constructor unless you really really mean it. It appears you're getting a null pointer exception because your variable is null, and it might be related to using `new` to create an activity.

I highly recommend you start with the [IAB API guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html), and once you're comfortable with the core concepts of IAB, then move on to the library.

Comment: I have edited my answer with the IBillingObserver and it always don't show me anything. Can you give me an example please :)

Comment: Please see DungeonsRedux for a very detailed example.

Comment: In dungeonRedux there is no IBillingObserver to see

Comment: Please reply or maybe do a tutorial step by step in which people can understand your library... I have edited my answer

Comment: Yes, there is. DungeonsRedux uses the convenience class AbstractBillingObserver, which implements IBillingObserver.

Comment: Can you please watch my re-edited answer and tell me why i have a nullpointerexception ?

Comment: So please remove from your README: "requestPurchase("com.example.item"). That's how simple it should be to use Android In-app Billing. And with this  library it is."

Comment: Check my latest edit regarding the null pointer exception. Regarding the library, no one is forcing you to use it. :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16394/discussion-between-hpique-and-smile-applications)